# Incorrect InputRFC format after getBytes

Tags: java, parsing, inputstream, saprfc

I am working on parameterized java mapping. While performing RFC lookup, code is returning payload in incorrect format. Please find below code and the stack trace.

```
 chn = LookupService.getChannel(getBSystem(),getCChannel());
 rfc = LookupService.getRfcAccessor(chn);
 getTrace().addInfo("After LookUp");
 String req = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"+"<ns0:OTC_NFE_MAIL_OUTPUT"+"xmlns:ns0=\"urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions\">"+"<I_ACCESS_KEY>"
    + idNFe + "<I_ACCESS_KEY></ns0:OTC_NFE_MAIL_OUTPUT>";
 getTrace().addInfo("Req value:"+req);
 InputStream inputRFC = new ByteArrayInputStream(req.getBytes());
 getTrace().addInfo("InputRFC"+inputRFC);
 XmlPayload rfcPayload = LookupService.getXmlPayload(inputRFC);
 getTrace().addInfo("rfcPayload"+rfcPayload);
 XmlPayload result = rfc.call(rfcPayload);
 getTrace().addInfo("Payload result"+result);
 InputStream resp = result.getContent();
```

Stack Trace:

- After LookUp
- Req value:35181204136367001755550010001002441406742916
- InputRFCjava.io.ByteArrayInputStream@7ec9dfbb
- rfcPayloadcom.sap.aii.mapping.lookup.XmlPayload@447072fe

We need 35181204136367001755550010001002441406742916 value to be populated while making the rfc call. Kindly tell me what changes needed to be done.

Comment: You're calling `toString()` on a `ByteArrayInputStream` and then on an `XmlPayload`. That doesn't do what you expect it to, basically. That doesn't mean the data is incorrect - although calling `String.getBytes()` without specifying a `Charset` is almost *always* a bad idea. In this case you should be specifying UTF-8.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for replying. In the previous iteration of code..I specified the UTF-8 format inside getBytes() but it still fetched the output simIlar to now.

Comment: Yes, it would - because the problem is calling `toString` on classes that don't override it. But that's just the trace output - there's no obvious indication that the payload is actually incorrect here.